# Does express-compress recompress gzipped content?

Tags: node.js, express, gzip

I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip package to serve gzipped assets and I need to gzip any assets that don't have a .gz (gzipped file) along with it.

So I tried to use express-compression below the code of serving pre gzipped content. so my code looks like this.

```
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
const compression = require('express-compression');
var app = express();

app.use("/", expressStaticGzip("/my/rootFolder/"));

app.use(compression())
```

express-static-gzip serves the pre gzipped asset.

So my question does the express compression package again compress the asset the is already gzipped if I use this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a good question.

But let me ask you some questions.
After we have archived the file into rar, iso or something like that,
we can rearchive it, but it doesn't make sense.
I mean the file size is not reduced, and almost the same.

So with the same engine, we don't need to archive it again.

Makes sense?

Comment: I don't want to recompress the files, If I use compression() to compress assets does it affect precompressed files? that's what I wanted to know. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Um, so you don't want to archive the file, but want to know if it is changed. I think if you use compression() again, the file content will be changed, and yes, it will affect the precompressed files.